# Giving control to shell from a C code?

Tags: c, linux, shell

How can I execute shell from a C code?

My shell is placed in `/bin/sh`

Following didn't seem to work for me

```
system("/bin/sh");
exec("/bin/sh");
```

Comment: Didn't work?  Can you elaborate on that?  And, which one of the exec family of functions did you use?

Comment: what happens? More details please

Comment: Actually when i run my C code without using any of those commands, my code goes into a kind of waiting state (that's because of the nature of C application I am using). I tried these commands before the line which makes it go into the wait state but I don't get any shell prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to tell the shell it should be interactive:

```
system("/bin/sh -i");
```

However, I believe that your original `system()` call should have produced a shell prompt too.

Both notations (with and without the '-i') in this program give me a shell prompt (return to the previous shell by typing 'exit' and <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>Control-D</kbd>):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    system("/bin/sh -i");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This program works as expected for me:

```
int main()
{
    int ret = system("/bin/sh");
    printf ("Shell returned %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

using -i causes some sort of redirection issue and everything hangs as soon as I type a command that produces output.

There are important differences between *system()* and *exec()*.  *system()* is effectively the same as `/bin/sh -c yourCommand` on the command line, so the `system("/bin/sh")` is the same as

```
/bin/sh -c /bin/sh
```

This is why it is rarely used, because the command you want is executed by first starting an unnecessary shell process.

*exec()* causes the entire process image to be replaced by the command specified so if I had written:

```
int main()
{
    int ret = exec("/bin/sh");
    printf ("Shell returned %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

The *printf()* and everything after it would never have been executed because the whole process transforms into an instance of */bin/sh*.  The proper way to run a child command is to fork and then exec in the child and wait in the parent.